# Android full-screen dialog callback issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am having trouble wrapping my head around something but let me first describe my setup:

[image: flow]

I have an activity that references 3  fragments, each one of them get shown at the correct time. This is how the ChildrenSpecificationFragment looks:

[image]

If the user clicks the floating action button the following DialogFragment opens:

[image]

I found the following information in the new material design guidelines: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs

> Avoid dialogs that:
>   Open additional dialogs from within a dialog.
>   Contain scrolling content, particularly alerts. Instead, consider alternate containers or layouts that are optimized for reading or interacting with significant amounts of content.
>
> Exceptions include:Full-screen dialogs may open additional dialogs, such as pickers, because their design accommodates additional layers of material without significantly increasing the app’s perceived z-depth or visual noise.

This is where my problems begin. The 'add child' dialog has scrollable content (in landscape mode) and when the user clicks 'Birth date' a date picker opens.

I am trying to find a way to implement a full screen dialog (as in the guidelines) that has a callback to the ChildrenSpecificationFragment, so that I can add the child to the RecyclerView .

I hope that my questing is clear and would greatly appreciate any input that would lead me to the solution. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what is your add child fragment's layout file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bhscbGu2

Comment: I've seen answers and other questions that use a FragmentTransaction to add the dialog, but I've yet to get it working.

Comment: Hey Jon, I found a way to make it work, I wrote a blog post about it yesterday: http://jeroendruwe.be/full-screen-dialogs-in-android/. Though I don't know if it's the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you have any luck with the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog. This doesn't work for me, but I'm also using the android design NavigtionView, which may affect it.

Comment: I did but my solution seemed beter for my case.

Comment: Is your problem with making a full-screen dialog fragment or is it about having a callback from a fragment to an other ?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that handles both.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use Dialog only? You could start a new activity (instead of full screen Dialog) and return the result (child info) in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Would you like a solution that establish a communication between fragments and/or activity?  In Java, it is not a callback. And, it is not clear to me what your code is like for showing the full-screen dialog. Is it in a fragment?

Comment: I was trying to open a full screen dialog from the fragment but it did not work out so I just created a new activity as explained in my post.

Comment: I thought you only have 1 Activity in your app. Do you now have 2 Activities?  If that's what you want, that may be fine but I don't think you had to do that.

Comment: I had only one but I did not figure out how to do it with 1 activity, do you have a solution?

Comment: There is a way to establish communication between fragments and/or activity, like I said previously. It is faster and safer I think. Do you want to redesign your app that way? It has been done by many developers, and recommended by Google.

Comment: If it looks the same as the 'fullscreen dialoog' it's fine by me, can you show me an example?

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you provided some code. You do however provide some good details on your app. With code snippet, perhaps that would attract more attention, advice for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see code from your post. So I am guessing your code structure as a start.
First build your dialog with a listener and process setPositiveButton() and the onClick event.

Code suggestion:

```
public class ChildrenSpecificationFragment extends Fragment {
...

public void passData(Object obj) {
}

   class SubChildFragment extends Fragment {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisContext);
       ...
       // Add the buttons...
       builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           ...
           passData(Object obj);   // pass data to the outer fragment class
```

Notes:

- `SubChildFragment`, for example, is an inner class derived from Fragment. It can call the public method `passData`() in the outer class `ChildrenSpecificationFragment` for passing any data you need.
- I am using an inner class because I think this is what you meant in your diagram by

> Add child full-screen fragment

- This coding technique is easier than starting a new Activity and Intent.

For showing **fullscreen dialogs**, there is a good Google webpage I think @ [Dialog - Fullscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Search text for "Showing a Dialog Fullscreen or as an Embedded Fragment".

Comment: But does this show the content of the layout in fullscreen as the example by google: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsTXVxUFJQdy15ZzA/components_dialogs_fullscreen1.png ?

Comment: Because this was how I originally had things, a fragment extending dialogfragment and calling a by the parent implemented interface method.

Comment: @Jdruwe, The fragment, SubChildFragment in my sample, can be the dialogFragment, and it can show the fullscreen. I think the dialog can be fullscreen by the layout specifications. The data passing is separate from the GUI layout. There is a link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html , in case you did not read this one.  I thought you have the fullscreen issue solved already.

Comment: @Jdruwe, I add more comments on the bottom about "fullscreen dialogs".

Comment: Thanks for your solution! :D How do you compare it to my solution described in: http://jeroendruwe.be/full-screen-dialogs-in-android/ ?

Comment: @Jdruwe, It's not easy to compare both code designs, mainly because your link shows partial code. Besides that, I like to use startActivity() only for launching other apps. So I avoid using it within only a specific app.  Another thing, you may upvote some answers if you think they are useful. And I notice some detailed answers that seem useful.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR - DialogFragment is insufficient for anything other than completely full-screen. Use an Activity instead.**

It is possible to make a `DialogFragment` full-screen (with the `ActionBar` shown), but it comes with lots of irritations.

A `DialogFragment` is, as the name suggests, a `Dialog` and a `Fragment` rolled into one: it can be treated as both a `Dialog`, using `show()` and `dismiss()`, or as a `Fragment`, using it with a `FragmentManager`.

As the [official documentation suggests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog), making a dialog completely full-screen (overlaying everything) is achieved by attaching the dialog to the root view `android.R.id.content`:

```
public void showDialog() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CustomDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();

    if (mIsLargeLayout) {
        // The device is using a large layout, so show the fragment as a dialog
        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "dialog");
    } else {
        // The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // For a little polish, specify a transition animation
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        // To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
        // for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment)
                   .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

To get the dialog to appear below the `ActionBar`, a `FrameLayout` is required which is used instead of the root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Use ThemeOverlay to make the toolbar and tablayout text
                 white -->
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/abl_top"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now comes the pain.

Depending on how the app's main navigation is setup, different hoops will need to be jumped through in order to get everything working perfectly.

The above example has a `NavigationView`. Since the home button `android.R.id.home` is handled in the main view, some logic is needed there to check if our dialog is shown so that the home button, which is now an `X`, will close the dialog. Returning `false` here allow the event to be handled in the dialog.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
            if (f instanceof MyDialogFragment) {
                return false;
            }
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also, the back button needs similar logic to determine whether the `NavigationView` needs closing or the `ActionBar` content resetting.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
        if (f instanceof MyDialogFragment) {
            final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            ab.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In the `DialogFragment` itself, the logic for closing the dialog (and abusing the `ActionBar`) needs to be implemented.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mActionBar != null) {
                mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
                mActionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
       case R.id.action_save:
            if (mOnAcceptListener != null) {
                mOnAcceptListener.onAccept();
            }
            if (mActionBar != null) {
                mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
                mActionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This alls feels really [kludgy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kludgy). Of course, if you're using a `TabLayout`, forget everything I've just said.

With a `TabLayout` you can just handle everything in the `DialogFragment`, but if you're using a `ViewPager`, it'll be impossible to get the dialog to cover the tabs but not the action bar. See [Show DialogFragment over TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141071/show-dialogfragment-over-tablayout).

That question (by me) has an answer that suggests the same as @Jdruwe, which is to forget the hopelessness of the `DialogFragment` and use an `Activity` instead.

Comment: So you are saying that I should stick with the solution I described in: http://jeroendruwe.be/full-screen-dialogs-in-android/ ?

Comment: I think so, yes. The DialogFragment route is too kludgy; though, maybe I'm not smart enough.

Answer (score 1):

A solution described on my blog using startActivityForResult(...): http://jeroendruwe.be/full-screen-dialogs-in-android/

Comment: Is that still using a DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to oncreate in your custom dialog fragment.

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

On the other hand, you can use content resolvers to store your children datas.
It has observer pattern. So each CursorAdapter attached to that content it refreshes itself without calling `notifySetDataChanged();`.

I think you are using RecyclerView.Adapter. You can use [this class.](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)

Another advice for implementing adding child feature is using `startActivityForResult(activity);`.
You can send back datas by using `getIntent().getExtras().put(key,value);` You can search for custom start activity for result.

Good luck

Comment: The setStyle does not work, this is the result if I use it: imgur.com/Zb5dtPP. And I don't really see how this could provide the 'up navigation' as in the guidelines.