# Fullscreen Dialog dismiss icon in black

Tags: android, material-design

This question is a follow-up to [Android Fullscreen dialog confirmation and dismissive actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074717/android-fullscreen-dialog-confirmation-and-dismissive-actions) which uses a *dark theme as per the image below*, and so the icons are displayed in white.

[image]

---

I want to **display the "X" icon in black**, because I am using a **light** theme.

The other question has an accepted solution for changing the `ActionBar` icon that looks like:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
```

That is displaying a white X, even though I am using a light theme.

---

I seem to remember there is a way to use that provided icon, and to theme it to display in black on a light background...?

Comment: and why don't you use a black/dark "X" image rather

Comment: I would like to use the system defaults as far as possible. (if possible). Then when a new style exists with a slightly different graphic, no need for me to update the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tinting the colour of the stock icons in this way is built into `support-v4` library, and described by Chris Banes on his blog:

- [Support Libraries v22.1.0](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/)

> The Drawable tinting methods added in Lollipop are super useful for
>   letting you dynamically tint assets. AppCompat had its own baked in
>   implementation in the v21 support library and we’ve now extracted that
>   into DrawableCompat in support-v4 for everyone to use.

```
Drawable drawable = ...;

// Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work
// on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);

// We can now set a tint
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
// ...or a tint list
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, myColorStateList);
// ...and a different tint mode
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

---

Which makes my exact code quite simple:

```
// set X close icon in black
Drawable drawable = getResources()
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLACK);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```

---

Related questions:

- [DrawableCompat tinting does not work on pre-Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872101/drawablecompat-tinting-does-not-work-on-pre-lollipop)
- [Android: Tint using DrawableCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788251/android-tint-using-drawablecompat)